# unable to process a function inside a view using navigation bar

Tags: django

I'm making a website using django and i have navigation bar that has a few items when i click on another item which is "delete" I am not able to see the page i intended to see
presently the 'insert' tab is my default tab and if i want to see the other link using delete tab i am not able

the views file is like this

```
    def home(request):
    form=insert()
    form1=insert()
    if request.method=="POST" and 'b1' in request.POST:
        form=insert(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request,'employee/form.html')
    if request.method=="POST" and 'b2' in request.POST:
        allobjs=emp.objects.all()
        return render(request,'employee/form.html',{'form1':allobjs})
    if request.method=="POST" and 'b3' in request.POST:

        allobjs=emp.objects.all().delete()
       #return render(request,'employee/form.html',{'form1':allobjs})


    return render(request,'employee/form.html',{'forms':form,'form1':form1})
    def dele(request):
       return render(request,'employee/emp.html')
```

my code for navigation bar is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">

        <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'employee-insert'  %}">Insert Record</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'employee-delete'  %}">Delete Record</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Update Records</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Assign Duties</a>
      </li>
      <li class='nav-item'>
          <a class='nav-link' href="">View The duties</a>
```

my app which is called employee has url.py like this

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='employee-insert'),
    path('',views.dele,name='employee-delete'),]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you import the view dele to the url, try to keep your action url like:
action={% url 'employee-dele' %}

Comment: What are you trying to say??....i have matched the url names properly , your suggestion tells me to just change the name i don't think it will work

Comment: i want you to give proper spacing btw them like i've given above.... spacing makes a huge difference in Django...if that still doesn't work out... can you put your code in GIT and i can have a check.

Comment: Yeah sure i can do that

Comment: please do provide the name  of the file you out on git over here on comments or you can copy paste the link to the git

Comment: [https://github.com/Harshith2396/django-miniproject ] this is the link to my project